# How to set endpt.disable_tcp_switch configuration?

Tags: android, react-native, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm using this library; https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip

I getting UDP size exceed error and need disable tcp switch setting. This settings in PJSIP this variable endpt.disable_tcp_switch (https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Using_SIP_TCP#switch).

This library using PJSUA2 (PJSIP SIP API) but setting ing PJSIP config. How to set endpt.disable_tcp_switch configuration ?

Thanks.